# Vaadin popup hints

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to have some hint below the table which will be display while the page load, then this will disappear. I know how to do this animation in css, but i completely confused of how to add this hint to java.

I want to have something like this: {IMG REMOVED}

I cant find a vaadin element for this, I'm not asking about "tooltip"

Answer (score 0):

I would reuse the html element showing the line numbers (1-10...) and attach your animation there. this will be shown until the lines are loaded so i guess it will fit your needs.
css class:

```
.v-table-scrollposition{ /* my animation */}
```